# Created AMI in region1 and want to start Inatance in region2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 AMI in region1. I however want to start an EC2 instance with this image in region2.

Seems like should be a common scanario, but I can't find a way to do this.

I prefer to use Elasticfox, but can use the command line tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to copy it to the zone in which you want to start the new instance.

From [Amazon EC2 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/FAQ_Regions_Availability_Zones.html):

> *How do I launch an AMI in another Region?*
>
> Simply copy your AMI from its current
>   bucket to a bucket located in the
>   Region where you want to launch the
>   AMI and register the AMI. For example,
>   to launch a US-based AMI in the EU
>   Region, you have to copy the AMI to an
>   Amazon S3 bucket that was created with
>   an EU location constraint. After the
>   AMI is copied, you must register the
>   AMI and use the obtained AMI ID for
>   launches in the new Region.
>
> Also, make sure to give read access to
>   the bucket, image manifest, and image
>   parts to ec2-bundled-images@amazon.com
>   for Windows AMIs, and
>   za-team@amazon.com for Linux AMIs.
>
> *What tools are available to help*
>   *migrate my AMIs to a new Region?*
>
> The API Tools contain a new command
>   called ec2-migrate-image. It is
>   designed to help migrate AMIs to a new
>   Region. Run ec2-migrate-image --help
>   for more details.